# Taking the Differences Between 2 Dates (R)

Tags: r, date, lubridate, subtraction

I am trying to take the difference between two dates in R. Normally, I could have just done this in MS Excel, but I want to try and learn something new by doing this in R. The dates are in the form : Year-Month-Date and are in "factor" format:

```
# how the data looks like
d <- data.frame (

"day_a" = c("2010-12-25", "2020-10-31"),
"day_b" = c("2011-12-24", "2021-01-01")

)

d$day_a = as.factor(d$day_a)
d$day_b = as.factor(d$day_b)
```

First, I tried to do a straightforward subtraction :

```
   #my first attempt to take the difference in days
    d$day_1 = as.Date(d$day_a, "%Y/%m/%d")
    d$day_2 = as.Date(d$day_b, "%Y/%m/%d")
    
    d$diff = d$day_1 - d$day_2
```

Then, I tried to use the "lubdridate" library:

```
library(lubridate)
d$diff=interval(ymd(d$day_1),ymd(d$day_2))
```

However, this also did not work.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a character input for dates. Also, you were using `%Y/%m/%d` and you defined in `d` data as `Y-m-d` so that the date conversion would work fine:

```
d <- data.frame (
  
  "day_a" = c("2010-12-25", "2020-10-31"),
  "day_b" = c("2011-12-24", "2021-01-01")
  
)

d$day_a = as.factor(d$day_a)
d$day_b = as.factor(d$day_b)

d$day_1 = as.Date(as.character(d$day_a))
d$day_2 = as.Date(as.character(d$day_b))

d$diff = d$day_1 - d$day_2
```

Output:

```
d
       day_a      day_b      day_1      day_2      diff
1 2010-12-25 2011-12-24 2010-12-25 2011-12-24 -364 days
2 2020-10-31 2021-01-01 2020-10-31 2021-01-01  -62 days
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! Suppose I want to remove the "days" in the column "diff" ... could I use this? d$new_col = as.numeric(d$diff)

Comment: @Noob Hi dear, yes you are right! and if you want positive values use `d$new_col = abs(as.numeric(d$diff))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple subtraction of `date` objects and convert the result to numeric:

```
d <- data.frame (
  day_a = c("2010-12-25", "2020-10-31"),
  day_b = c("2011-12-24", "2021-01-01")
)

d$timediff <- as.numeric(as.Date(d$day_b) - as.Date(d$day_a))

       day_a      day_b timediff
1 2010-12-25 2011-12-24      364
2 2020-10-31 2021-01-01       62
```

Note that the new column contains the time difference in days.